# Unique paths Dynamic Programming

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

You have a 2D grid. You have a limited number of moves. You can go right, down, left, and up. And you need to find the number of ways to escape the grid. So a 1 x 2 grid with 3 moves has 9 unique paths to escape the grid (escaping is going out of bounds).

I need to come up with a dynamic programming approach and so far I can only think about the different moves you can have:

1. You are on the grid and not out of moves: keep going
2. You are out of bounds and out of moves: 1 + try to find another path
3. You are out of bounds and not out of moves: 1 + go back a step and find another path
4. You are on the gird and out of moves: this path does not count, go back a step and find another path

I can't think of a way of storing the values to avoid recalculation since you can start at any point and there are multiple places to finish from, as well as having a limited number of moves.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, on a  1x2 grid you can escape the grid by moving: {up},{down},{left},{right,right}, {right, up}, {right, down}. - I get 6. What am I missing to get 9? Do you have to take 3 moves? Maybe add a picture or a more detailed example.

Comment: So the idea is that you can keep moving until you are out of moves. So after the 6 paths, there's still the possibility of moving to the next square then moving back to the starting square then escaping. 6 + 3 = 9